# String replacement from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace my column depending upon data from another dataframe.
Have to search for respective "name" from the other dataframe and include the "change_name" in the df1

df1:

```
ID  name
1   cat
2   jack
3   snake
4   monkey
```

df2:

```
name    change_name
cat     meow
jack    oooo 
snake   ssss
monkey
```

output:

```
ID  name
1   cat      meow
2   jack     oooo
3   snake    ssss
4   monkey   nan
```

Sorry, I had to edit my question.

I had to do like below:

```
def map_name(name):
    elif name == 'cat':
        return 'meow'
    elif name == 'jack':
        return 'oooo'
    elif name == 'snake':
        return 'ssss'
    elif name == 'monkey ':
        return None
    else
        return name
```

`df1['name'] = df1['name'].apply(map_name)`

As the list is small, I have hardcoded here but the list might grow. Can someone tell how to do teh same functionality using dataframes?

Comment: Use `merge` with `dropna`, i.e. `df.merge(df2.dropna(),on="name")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(df1["name"], df1["change_name"])}

df["new_name"] = df["name"].map(d)

df.dropna(subset=["new_name"], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

output:

```
    ID  name    new_name
0   1   cat     meow
1   2   jack    oooo
2   3   snake   ssss
```

Comment: dict comprehension is not necessary, check dupe.