# Fetch data from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I had asked a question earlier but it was closed as the initial question was considered as duplicate.

But I am trying to something different from that thread as well as duplicate thread.

[String Replacement From Another DataFrame.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294121/string-replacement-from-another-dataframe)

So please don't close this thread.
Thanks.

I need to replace my column depending upon data from another dataframe.
Have to search for respective "name" from the other dataframe and include the "change_name" in the df1

DataFrame 1:

```
ID  name
1   cat
2   jack
3   snake
4   monkey
```

DataFrame 2:

```
name    change_name
cat     meow
jack    oooo 
snake   ssss
monkey 
note    money
pencil pen
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  name
1   cat      meow
2   jack     oooo
3   snake    ssss
4   monkey   nan
5   note    money
6   pencil pen
```

I had to do like below:

```
def map_name(name):
    elif name == 'cat':
        return 'meow'
    elif name == 'jack':
        return 'oooo'
    elif name == 'snake':
        return 'ssss'
    elif name == 'monkey ':
        return None
    else
        return name
```

`df1['name'] = df1['name'].apply(map_name)`

As the list is small, I have hardcoded here but the list might grow. Can someone tell how to do the same functionality using dataframes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple merge would do it.
And then since you want the rows in `df2` which are not in `df1` concat them.

```
pd.concat([df1.merge(df2),df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]]
```

Result:

```
In [23]: pd.concat([df1.merge(df2),df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]])
Out[23]: 
    ID    name change_name
0  1.0     cat        meow
1  2.0    jack        oooo
2  3.0   snake        ssss
3  4.0  monkey        None
4  NaN    note       money
5  NaN  pencil         pen
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error.  `finalDF=pd.concat([df1.merge(df2),df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]]`  ```Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'```

Comment: You're welcome. What version of pandas are you on? You should have 1.0.1. Check with `pd.__version__`...

Comment: `0.25.3` is the version.

Comment: You should upgrade your pandas. Something like `pip install -U pandas`...

Comment: Yes, I upgraded pandas and it resolved the issue. But I am not able to see the contents when df2 doesn't have the 'names', essentially the last condition in my earlier code    ```else
        return name```

Comment: Can you rephrase the concern? I'm not following.

Comment: ```note    money
pencil pen ``` are not getting   displayed in my final concatenated dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share what command you're running and the result you're getting? Thanks.

Comment: Output is like tthe following...........................                                                          0  1.0     cat        meow
1  2.0    jack        oooo
2  3.0   snake        ssss
3  4.0  monkey        None

Comment: Commnadline ```finalDF=pd.concat([df1.merge(df2),df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]]```